# How can I have the default resourceful route include attributes of my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, attributes, rails-routing, restful-url

*(Note that the examples are a simplification of my use case.)*

I have a Model **Event** and the default route for showing one event:

`/events/:id(.:format) ----> activities#show`

Now, the event has an attribute named year and I am also *already* accepting the following route:

`/events/:year/:id(.:format) ----> activities#show`

As the second variant shall be the default, I want code like `redirect_to @event` to lead the user to that variant (e.g. http://localhost:3000/events/2012/1).

**Where do I define that?**

So far, I've tried to overwrite `to_param` in the model like so:

```
def to_param
  "#{self.year}/#{self.id}"
end
```

... but that will cause `params[:id]` to be filled with the string **2012/1** .

I want `params[:id]` to still be *1* while `params[:year]` should be *2012*.

**Does Rails provide a standard way to accomplish this?**

... or will I have to write a custom method for the model and call it by issuing something like this: `redirect_to @event.custom_method_to_create_long_url_variant`

Such a method would be quickly implemented, but if Rails can handle the requirement via a simple setting, it would allow me to leave pretty much all other code untouched.

**EDIT:**

I found out that my `params` held the values (:id and :year) as expected when changing the **get** in the functional test FROM `get :show, id: @event` TO `get :show, id: @event.id`.

Now the question is:

**Is that just the way to do it or can I still support `get :show, id: @event` ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something, like this:

```
match "/events(/:year)/:id(.:format) => "activities#show"
```

and get in your controller

```
Started GET "/events/2012/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-14 17:25:44 +0400
Parameters: {"year"=>"2012", "id"=>"12"}
```

or without year

```
Started GET "/events/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-14 17:25:44 +0400
Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
```

so, you can use in your controller

```
params[:id]
params[:year]
```

And url_helper

```
match "/events(/:year)/:id(.:format) => "activities#show", :as => :my_event

my_event_path(2012, 12) #=> /eventes/2012/12
my_event_path(@event.id) #=> /events/12
```